# Struct padding, size, and abi.encode

Tags: solidity, memory

I have the following structure and want to compute its hash:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    uint8 field1;
    int24 field2;
    uint256 field3;
}
```

I was expecting that due to packing the size of this structure is 64 bytes, as the first two fields fit in a single 32-byte slot. However I tested it with this code:

```
SomeStruct memory s = SomeStruct(0x13, 0x567890, type(uint256).max - 100000000000);
bytes32 h1 = keccak256(abi.encode(s));
bytes32 h2;
assembly("memory-safe") {
    h2 := keccak256(s, mul(32, 3))
}
```

After this, both hashes `h1` and `h2` are equal. Does packing only apply to structs in storage rather than structs in other memory types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does packing only apply to structs in storage rather than structs in other memory types?

Yes. From the Solidity docs' [*Layout of State Variables in Storage*](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html):

> It might be beneficial to use reduced-size types if you are dealing with storage values because the compiler will pack multiple elements into one storage slot, and thus, combine multiple reads or writes into a single operation. [...]
>
> When dealing with function arguments or memory values, there is no inherent benefit because the compiler does not pack these values.

The article [*Layout in Memory*](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_memory.html) has an [example for `struct`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_memory.html#example-for-difference-in-struct-layout):

> The following struct occupies 96 bytes (3 slots of 32 bytes) in storage, but 128 bytes (4 items with 32 bytes each) in memory.
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     uint a;
>     uint b;
>     uint8 c;
>     uint8 d;
> }
> ```